# Php button handling

Tags: php, html

I have created a button, now i want to change a variable's value and pass into anothor php file when the button is pressed. I have tried to find some infirmation from google but couldn't find something useful. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: You need to read a php forms tutorial..

Comment: @Dominique Lorre But i think using forms is not useful for what i am tring to do, i know the post and get methods and how to use them, setting an action so the program will know where to send the data to. What i want to do is: i will create 5 buttons, i have one global variable, each buttons will give different values to global variable then no matter which is pressed they all will direct to the same ****.php file. At final, i will be able to understand which button has been pressed by checking the global variable, that's completely what i want to do. Do you have any suggestions for this? Or m

Comment: Or maybe a link

Comment: @user6568979 that's almost exactly what forms are for. User chooses a value, you press a button which submits the form and sends the result to the server. Your server can read the value selected by the user, and you can process the data based on that. HTML forms + PHP is a good solution. Using a radio button list rather than 5 buttons would be more user friendly and easier to process as a form variable. You can use CSS to make them look like buttons of course, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose your button is a link such that

```
<a href="?set=1">Click here</a>
```

On click of this button when page would load get the query string parameter like below:

```
<?php
$var = "someValue";
if(isset($_GET['set']) && $_GET['set'] == true){
  $var = "ChangedValue";
  header("Location:abc.php?val="$var);
}
?>
```

and get the val in the other file.